# Calculate the delta between two time intervals for sending messages

Tags: splunk, splunk-formula, splunk-dashboard

Good afternoon!
We receive messages on splunk, now test ones, of this type:

```
{
   "event": "Sourcetype test please", 
   "sourcetype": "testsystem-2", 
   "host": "some-host-123", 
   "fields": 
   {
  "messageId": "ED280816-E404-444A-A2D9-FFD2D171F928",
  "srcMsgId": "rwfsdfsfqwe121432gsgsfgd3",
  "Correlation_srcMsgId": "",
  "baseSystemId": "abc1",
  "routeInstanceId": "abc2",
  "routepointID": "abc3",
  "eventTime": "1985-04-12T23:20:50Z", 
  "messageType": "abc4",
  "GISGMPRequestID": "PS000BA780816-E404-444A-A2D9-FFD2D1712345",
  "GISGMPResponseID": "PS000BA780816-E404-444B-A2D9-FFD2D1712345",
  "resultcode": "abc7",
  "resultdesc": "abc8"
  }
}
```

The task is as follows: there is a time period between the first message and the second, and also between the second and the third. The task is that you need to somehow calculate the delta between these intervals and display it on the dashboard. This is real?
And the question is, how can I do this? Is there a rough example?
Unfortunately, I have not worked with splunk at all before, so I don’t even know where to start. If you need leading questions, I'm ready to answer.

Answer (score 1):

To find the difference in numeric fields (including `_time`) between events, use the `range` function of the `streamstats` command.  The function computes the difference between the lowest and highest values of the given field.  When the set of values is limited to 2 by the `window` option then you get the delta from one event to the next.

```
index=foo
| streamstats window=2 range(_time) as diff
```

There's also the `delta` command, which is similar.

```
index=foo
| delta _time as diff
```

Comment: Adding "| delta _time as timediff"" in my query:
```
index="bl_logging" sourcetype="testsystem-2"
| transaction maxpause=5m srcMsgId Correlation_srcMsgId messageId
| table _time srcMsgId Correlation_srcMsgId messageId duration eventcount
| delta _time as timediff
```
Works great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: But as it turned out, my task is a little more difficult.
delta _time as timediff - works great with messages that arrive sequentially, but there is one problem: messages arrive chaotically from different sources. As it turned out, I need to calculate the delta from messages in one thread.

Comment: Messages in the same thread have a common srcMsgId (not different as I thought), but each message has an individual messageId. Thus, I need the message threads to be grouped by srcMsgId, and the delta is calculated from the messages strictly in this thread (group). Calculate the interval between the first and second messages in the group, the second and third, etc.
Perhaps you know how to edit my request?

Comment: Sorting my srcMsgId may help or use `| streamstats window=2 range(_time) as timediff by srcMsgId`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I combined all your recommendations, added a little to the request what I found in the documentation.
And I got it right:

index="bl_logging" sourcetype="testsystem-2"

| transaction maxpause=5m srcMsgId Correlation_srcMsgId messageId

| table _time srcMsgId Correlation_srcMsgId messageId duration eventcount

| sort srcMsgId _time

| streamstats current=f window=1 values(_time) as prevTime by subject

| eval timeDiff=_time-prevTime

| delta _time as timediff

I added: | delta _time as timediff